# Direct Credit Card Payment is not working in US based account in IOS app?

Tags: ios, paypal

My PayPal account is US based, I Create a app in developer.paypal.com and used it's client id in my App. But Direct credit card payment is not allowed? I make a transaction in Florida but it is failed.

Comment: What code you have done? What error you are getting??

Comment: I got the error message: "The Merchant does not accept payments of this type"

Comment: can you provide your complete response along with error codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an US business account, they can't make Direct credit card payment with REST API directly.
They need to enable direct credit card first:
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus

To enable this feature, they will be required to provide the information as below:

'To enable direct credit card processing, please provide addition information about yourself and your business.

To meet regulatory requirements, we need to collect your business details. This may include:

U.S Business owner Social Security Number, date of birth, and other personal details.
U.S Business Tax ID (EIN, ITIN) and other business information.'

Comment: i'm faceing the problem, *android paypal SDK* : merchant does not accept payments of this type

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use direct credit card payment, please make sure your account is a Business-Pro account, otherwise, direct credit card payment feature in your app is disabled.
Upgrade business to Pro: https://registration.paypal.com/onboardingPage.do?bundleType=C3&country=US&partner=PayPal .

Comment: That's incorrect. For US Business accounts, you can do Direct Credit card payments via REST API.

Comment: I am using iOS SDK , which provided by developer.paypal.com

Comment: can you provide your complete response along with error codes?

Comment: @techycommerce PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT - The merchant does not accept payments of this type. (401) | PayPal Debug-ID: a7d79189305c7 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.10.2]

Answer (score 0):

Your account is not registered in U.S . Its a Colombian account. REST API (credit card payments) are supported only in

- U.S ( a business account).
- U.K (you need a PRO account)

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/